# Trouble saving ALL listbox data

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

Ok, so i'm trying to make an Injector. To load the DLLs, I used a File Dialog to select the DLL then write the info to a List Box. Now I want to save the data in the list box and reload the past data on the Form Load, but every method I have tried only saves the name of the DLL not the other info such as Location.

I would like to have no external files IF possible. Any solutions?

Cheers.

Edit: Source code for Open File Dialog

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As

```
System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Substring(OpenFileDialog1.FileName.LastIndexOf("\"))
    Dim DLLfileName As String = FileName.Replace("\", "")
    ListBox1.Items.Add(DLLfileName)
    dlls.Add(DLLfileName, OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: No external files? Where do you want it saved?

Comment: Settings, but i can do an external file if necessary

Comment: What settings? User Settings is an external file. Registry Setting is an external file. Also, if you want help on this web site, you need to show what code you have tried. It is easier to tell you to change one word in one line than write your program for you!

Comment: Theres the source code for the Open File Dialog idk if it helps any, I tried saving the Items in an ArrayList but for some reason its not showing up in User Settings, even if I browse its not there.

Comment: An ArrayList is a list of things in memory. User Settings are in a file on your hard drive. You should probably create a user setting that is a collection (which is always strings) and then add your information to that collection, when you want to save it. Then you can read from that collection after you reload the project. If you want 2 values stored, you will have to have 2 collections and sync the values or, put both strings into one item in the collection separated by a unique character. Then split them out when needed.